# Google Spreadsheet - is there any way to export conditional fomatting script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a lot of conditional formatting on one of my sheets. I would like to export it as an app script so that I can use it on any other sheets (of the same type) in the future.

I know how to create conditional formatting using scripts but could not find out how to reverse engineer one if done manually within the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no programmatic access to conditional formatting in either Google Apps Script or the Spreadsheet API. All you can do is get the current format (in Apps Script only).

[Issue 162](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=162):     Ability to set conditional formatting in SpreadsheetApp

That request has been active since 2010. I don't see one for reading conditional formatting, but this one should suffice.